# Google Play Beta: 'App not available for this account' message

Tags: android, join, google-play, beta-testing, google-groups

Has anyone ran into an issue where all members of the *Google Beta Group* are able to get the beta version no problem except one. This one user -- who has a valid gmail address -- has joined the Google Grouped used for the beta testing. As the admin I can see they have the status of *member*.

When they click the URL provided for everyone to join the beta for the given application they get a message:

[image: Error message where user should be able to click the button to join the beta]

I removed them from the group after there were issues and then invited them again. This time I watched them to ensure the invite went to the proper gmail address as well as watched them accept the invite to the Google Group. Then when they clicked the URL to join accept/join the beta -- that has worked for 10+ others -- did not work for this user.

Once again I'll mention:

- I checked Chrome and they are logged in under the same account the invite was sent to
- I can see they have accepted the invite to the beta group and that in the group they are listed as a *member*
- All the others who have been able to successfully join and download the beta version and were able to click the accept beta invite button after following the beta URL where this user sees the "App not available for this account" message

**Any Suggestions?**

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be a glitch with Google Groups that was later resolved. Google Groups will be going away soon so this is no longer relevant.