# Google Play Alpha: App not available for this account

Tags: android, google-play, release

I released my app on Google Play Alpha. I added testers through lists of email addresses by selecting "Closed Alpha Testing" under "Choose a testing method". So to be clear, this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999010/google-play-beta-app-not-available-for-this-account-message), since I'm not using Google groups.

However, when I then open the Opt-in URL (https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.my.app), I get the message **"App not available for this account"**:

[image: App not available for this account]

I'm 100% sure I'm signed in to the right Google account, and everyone else I invited also gets this error. I also did not receive any email regarding the invite, like some people suggested should happen when I googled it.

Currently, it's been about 2 hours since I've published the app to the alpha track, and nothing has changed.

How can I test the app on the closed alpha track?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Comment: Check email list for this version.

Comment: @Tim I answered the question myself now. I agree it's a bit off-topic, though I think with the answer added, it could help others running into this issue, since I couldn't find any other posts with this answer and Google forums aren't always on point.

Comment: @Tim that's not off-topic in any way. Quite a relevant question to google play topic

Comment: @Farid "When do I get paid for my app revenue?" is also a question relevant to google play topic. Do you think that is not off topic in any way either?

Comment: @Tim, hey here is another "customer support" related off-topic question for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896956/google-app-is-published-on-internal-test-track-but-cant-be-found-downloaded. Don't you waste your time here with me  flag it as duplicate or off-topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It took a while to activate. It seems now (a day later), the link does work. Though this delay wasn't clear (to me at least) from the Play Console interface.

Note: I also never received an email about the activation.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  It's been two days.  Have you experienced this at all after your initial question?  Trying to launch an app during the COVID-19 situation, I'm starting to think that has something to do with it (staff shortages, etc).  Looking for any insight.

Comment: @ja408 I don't think I had to wait more than two days, though it might be possible.

Comment: @ja408 how much longer did it take for you? I'm waiting as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after I uploaded a new apk.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/230269935/app-not-available-for-this-account-internal-testing-invite-not-working?hl=en